# create word doc file from linux command line

Tags: linux, command-line, ms-word, openoffice.org, doc

I have some HTML files that I need to distribute in MS Word doc format (don't ask!). I can manually open each in OpenOffice and then save as a doc file. But I have quite a few files so I want to automate this. Do you know a way?

Comment: why does someone think this question should be closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Havn't tested but there is [pyuno](http://udk.openoffice.org/python/python-bridge.html#intro) package to access OpenOffice API and following program show some ways to do like that.

[ooextract.py](http://udk.openoffice.org/python/samples/ooextract.py)

> A command line tool, that extracts the
>   text, html or pdf content from a
>   StarWriter document and writes it to a
>   different file or (optionally) prints
>   it to stdout (grep your office
>   documents).

Comment: looks neat - I will try it out

Answer (score 1):

[Abiword](http://www.abisource.com/) can [convert files from the command line](http://opensource.weblogsinc.com/2005/06/29/use-abiword-to-convert-filetypes-on-the-command-line/).

I haven't personally tried it to convert HTML to DOC, but since it supports both those formats, it seems like it's worth a try.

Also, would RTF be good enough?  There are [lots of converters for HTML->RTF](http://www.google.com/search?q=html+to+rtf).

Comment: seems abiword can render to RTF but not doc from command line