# Is there software (scripts/libraries) in PHP that will read and write to Microsoft Office (2007 - 2011) Word Documents?

Tags: php, open-source, ms-office

I need a software library that will enable me to open a a Word Template document and populate the information dynamically (e.g. when a user logs into an account and downloads the document it should be populated with their information.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Create a word .doc file from a .doc template in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000882/how-to-create-a-word-doc-file-from-a-doc-template-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes...

http://phpword.codeplex.com/

http://www.phpdocx.com

Just 2 I found on Google! The first I've used before....

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it yet but, http://www.phpdocx.com/