# Can we create a word template using php?

Tags: php

I have create a word application to automate the word document editing.Is it possible to create a word template using php

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking out phpLiveDocx: http://www.phplivedocx.org/

And some other questions on SO that might be worth reading:

- [Use PHP to create a DOC file on a Unix Box based on an HTML webform selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587890/use-php-to-create-a-doc-file-on-a-unix-box-based-on-an-html-webform-selection)
- [Create Word Document using PHP in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124959/create-word-document-using-php-in-linux)

  - [Reading/Writing a MS Word file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php)
  - [create word doc file from linux command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921121/create-word-doc-file-from-linux-command-line)